# How to suppress emacsclient --eval output

Tags: emacsclient

I am opening a file as follows:

```
$ emacsclient -qt -e '(progn (find-file "'filename.py'"))'
#<buffer filename.py>
```

which outputs `#<buffer filename.py>` in the terminal. Is it possible to suppress that output?

---

I have tried following which didn't help.

```
$ emacsclient -qt -e '(progn (find-file "'Driver.py'"))' 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to suppress that output?

In general you can specify the `--suppress-output`/`-u` option:

```
$ emacsclient -e '(1+ 2)'
3
$ emacsclient -ue '(1+ 2)'
$
```

In your particular `find-file` examples you don't need the `--eval`/`-e` option:

```
$ emacsclient -t filename.py Driver.py
```

See [`(info "(emacs) emacsclient Options")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html) for more.